# PowerShell takes ~10 seconds to execute first command, but only inside OpenSSH Server

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh

I have OpenSSH for Windows (server and client) installed on multiple PCs.  The problem only occurs on one particular PC, but it's my main desktop:

*Scenario #1:*

- I `ssh` into my main desktop PC (let's call it `host1`) from any ssh client (remote or localhost, Windows OpenSSH, ssh on Ubuntu 20.04, ssh on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL, etc.)
- Execute `powershell.exe -NoProfile`
- Start typing a command (e.g. `Write-Host "Hello"` or `Get-ChildItem`)
- Result:  About a **10 second delay** before the characters of the command appear
- After that, everything works as expected; no unexpected delays

*Scenario #2:*

- `ssh host1 powershell.exe` (also tried with `ssh -t host1 powershell.exe` and `ssh -tt host1 powershell.exe`)
- Execute any command in PowerShell (e.g. `Get-ChildItem`)
- Result:  While the command appears immediately, there's around a **10 second delay** before the results are returned
- Execute the same (or any other command) in PowerShell
- Result: Executes immediately

*Scenario #3:*

- `ssh host1 powershell.exe Get-ChildItem`
- Result: About a **10 second delay** before the results appear
- `ssh host1 powershell.exe Get-ChildItem` again
- Result:  Still a **10 second delay** on each future invocation

*Scenario #4:*

- `ssh host1 powershell.exe -NoProfile`
- Result: About a **10 second delay** before the shell appears
- After the shell appears, everything works as normal

*Scenario #5:*

- From a command prompt in Windows, just execute powershell.exe
- Result:  No problem.  This only occurs when running under sshd.

*Scenario #6:*

- `ssh -t host1 wsl.exe`
- Result:  Works as expected with no delays in input or command results

*Scenario #7:*

- `ssh host1`
- Type a command that doesn't exist `jkjkjk`
- Result:  About a **10 second delay** before returning error
- So it's not *just* PowerShell, but cmd only results in a long delay on an error

*Scenario #8:*

- `ssh host1`
- Type a command that does exist and results in console output (I used Sysinternals `whois.exe`)
- Result: Returns immediately as expected with no delays

*Scenario #9:*

- Enabled [remoting over ssh on PowerShell Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1)
- `Enter-PSSession -HostName host1` (both with public-key as well as password auth; both from local host1 as well as from host2)
- Result: About a **10 second delay** before the prompt appears in the remote session

*Scenario #10:*

- Set PowerShell Core as the default shell for OpenSSH Server
- Execute `ssh host1 wsl.exe ls`
- Results:  Returns immediately - No problem

*Scenario #11:*

- With PowerShell Core set as the default shell as in #10
- Execute `ssh host1 Get-ChildItem`
- Result:  Back to the **10 second delay** before results appear
- *Why does running `wsl.exe ls` return its results immediately in the same PowerShell Core subshell that stalls out on a basic `gci`?*

#### What I've tried

As mentioned, this only happens on my main desktop.  I have another desktop that has almost the exact same configuration where this doesn't happen.  Obviously there must be *some* difference.

So on the PC with the long delay, I've:

- Uninstalled OpenSSH Server, deleted the HKLM:/SOFTWARE/OpenSSH registry keys, renamed `C:\ProgramData\ssh`, renamed my `%userprofile%/.ssh`, rebooted, then reinstalled OpenSSH server.

  - Result: Same problem
- Tried with PowerShell Core (`pwsh.exe`)

  - Result: Same problem
- Tried fully qualified path to PowerShell (`ssh host1 c:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoProfile`)

  - Result: Same problem
- Tried running `sshd.exe` in debug mode as per [these instructions](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Troubleshooting-Steps).  First tried with `sshd.exe -v`:

  - Result:  Uh, no delay!
  - What does this tell us?
- Tried running the same step above, but using `psexec -s` as per the debugging instructions to run it under the SYSTEM account.

  - Result:  Back to the same problem again - delay in all cases.
  - What does this tell us?
- Captured the debugging output of the previous two attempts into files and `diff`'d them.

  - Result:  No essential differences in the output other than key signing and PIDs
- Created a `testuser` in Windows and `ssh testuser@host1 powershell.exe`

  - Result:  No problem.

So this tells me that it is something in my user.  What, I'm still not sure.

- Renamed my `%userprofile%/Documents/WindowsPowerShell` and `%userprofile%/Documents/PowerShell` (PowerShell core) directories and tried again.

  - Result:  Same problem
  - Didn't have much hope for this since it was happening under both PowerShell and PowerShell Core, which use different profile directories anyway.
- Emptied `%temp%`

  - Result: No change - Same problem
- Uninstalled PowerShell in `optionalfeatures.exe` and reinstalled

  - Result: Same problem

Any ideas on where to look next?  I really don't want to have to blow away my entire user profile if I can avoid it.

Comment: Powershell has to load your installed modules on first start as well as your profile - is there a difference in installed/loaded modules between your desktops? check with `get-module`.

Comment: Alternate suggestion - If you're using powershell remotely, use its built-in remote shell via `Enter-PSSession "MyOtherPC"`? Assuming your clients have powershell as well of course.

Comment: Thanks @user19702 - The only modules installed on the "problem" computer are `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`, `PSReadline`, and (under Windows PowerShell, but not Core), `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`.  On the "good" desktop, the exact same modules are installed in Windows PowerShell, but I didn't have the Management module there.  Just for the heck of it, I did a `remove-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`, but that made no difference.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't have high hopes that it was the issue anyway -- If it was, then I would think that the problem would occur under *both* `psexec -s sshd.exe` and user-account `sshd.exe`.  The same modules would get loaded (once the SYSTEM sshd launched PowerShell into the user account) either way, right?  As it is, the problem doesn't occur under user-account `sshd.exe -d`.

Comment: As for remoting, unfortunately my typical daily driver is the fish shell on WSL.

Comment: Also, just tried PowerShell remoting over ssh, which has the same problem.  Added that as "Scenario #9" in the question.